# Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) warnings in Book with no floats or math, just simple headings (Part and Chapter) and text

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, titlesec, document-classes, warnings

So I have this relatively simple-coded `book` document. 
When I try to compile it, I get a lot of `Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active` warnings (though there's only one in provided MWE). The structure of the `book` is simple: just headings and text.
For instance, the page starts with Part Number, Chapter Number and text (yes I also have an images both between Part Number and Chapter Number, and Chapter Number and text added with `\includegraphics` command). But even if I delete those images, the warnings still pop up with even more warnings! 
I had a problem with the bottom line of the text being hung above the frame before, but that was solved with adding `heightrounded` to the `geometry` of the book. 
I understand that `book` class uses `\flushbottom` by default to literally flush the text to the bottom of the frame. So I tried to use `\raggedbottom` as many had suggested but that, while having solved the warning occurrence, introduced another problem: now on some pages the bottom line's baseline is getting hung above the frame, sometimes as high as almost a full line (unfortunately it's not that noticeable in MWE but you can still see it on Page 1)! 
So I am puzzled with what causes those warnings to pop up, since my document is fairly simple-coded?!
I noticed though that it's somehow connected to the way my headings (Part Number and Chapter Number, and probably images too) are spaced. Because when I remove all the `\part` and `\chapter` commands and leave only bare text, the warnings disappear. Has it got anything to do with `titlesec` package? 
I left all the `packages` used in my document intact, so you could easily spot if one of them is the issue. 
P.S: Don't mind those `Overfull \hbox` warnings, I don't have them in my text. They only appear when `\lipsum` is used.

```
% !TEX TS-program = LuaLaTeX
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openany]{book}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}[
]
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[shortcuts]{extdash}
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno} 
\usepackage[
  paperwidth=6in,
  paperheight=9in,
  inner=13mm,
  top=15mm,
  outer=20mm,
  bottom=24mm, showframe,
  heightrounded,
]{geometry} 

\usepackage{lettrine}
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
\renewcommand{\DefaultLoversize}{0.1} 
\renewcommand{\DefaultLraise}{0} 
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{}
\setlength{\DefaultFindent}{\fontdimen2\font}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0ex} 
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0ex}%
  \fancyhf[lef,rof]{\thepage}%
}
 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{\par}{}{}
\makeatother

%\raggedbottom % If used, it messes up the bottom line the way that its baseline hangs above the frame on some pages

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleclass{\part}{top}
\titleformat{\part}{\centering\normalfont\large}{\thepart.}{4ex}{\LARGE\centering}
\titlespacing*{\part}{0ex}{2ex}{0ex} 
\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\centering\normalfont\large}{\thechapter.}{4ex}{\large\centering}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0ex}{6ex}{02ex} 

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document} 
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\addtocounter{page}{0}

\begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    {\large TITLE\par}
    \vfill
    \title{SOME TITLE}
    \author{SOME AUTHOR}
    \date{}
\end{titlepage}
\clearpage
\frontmatter

\mainmatter

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\part{PART ONE}
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[height=15ex,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
  \end{center} 
\chapter{CHAPTER ONE}
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[height=35ex,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}
  \end{center} 
\lipsum[1-12]
\chapter{CHAPTER TWO}
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[height=35ex,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}
  \end{center} 
\lipsum[1-12]
\chapter{CHAPTER THREE}
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[height=35ex,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}
  \end{center} 
\lipsum[1-12]  
\end{document}
```

Comment: you are removing all flexibility with commands such as `titlespacing*{\chapter} {0ex}{6ex}{02ex}` so tex has no way to meet the  `\flushbottom` constraint that you have specified. Use `\raggdbottom` or allow some stretch around section headings

Comment: `raggedbottom` messes up the bottom line as I described in my question. How else can I control the spacing before and after `\part` and `\chapter` if not with `titlespacing` command without removing all flexibility of `book` class default `\flushbottom`? Direct me to some manuals I can read if you don’t have time to explain.

Comment: You are setting inconsistent unachievable constraints, so you need to change the constraints so they are possible to achieve, or ignore the warnings that TeX failed to achieve them. You don't really need a manual, it is simple math, you are specifying the bottom baseline should be at a fixed position. but from the top of the page you are stacking text with no flexibiliy, and heading size not a muliple of baselineskip, so at the bottom of the page the last baseline is not where it is specified to be but TeX has no way to move it, so the page is always short and infinitely underfull

Comment: I do understand the idea but the question remains: 1) How do I control the spacing before and after the heading (either `part` or `chapter`) so the values would not be fixed? If not `ex`, what would it be? Or `titlespacing` command is not an option at all? I understand that having the `ex` values for the spacing means having fixed values on a page which block flexibility;  and 2) How do I set the heading size in multiple of `baselineskip`? What unit of measure should I use?

Comment: use values like `1ex plus 1ex minus .5ex` so it tries to be between .5 and 2ex  look a any documn class, repor for example which has `{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}` for section

Comment: It’s still confusing (don’t forget that I’m not an expert in Tex). But you pointed me to what the problem is (fixed spacing and heading font size). I’ll dig into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some flexibility around headings so that flushbottom may be achieved

perhaps

```
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0ex}{6ex plus 4ex minus 1ex}{2ex}
```

But the underfull warning from the page before chapter 3 is because you removed the normal `\clearpage` but the heading and image do not fit and there is no glue to fill the page, you could perhaps add `\filbreak` like this to allow pages before chapters to be short.

```
\titleformat{\chapter}{\filbreak\centering\normalfont\large}{\thechapter.}{4ex}{\large\centering}
```

Comment: Adding values like `{6ex plus 4ex minus 1ex}` along with adding `\filbreak` to `\titleformat` eliminates the warnings but it also adds up empty pages and starts both `part` and `chapter` on a new page. And my intent is to have `part` and `chapter` on the same page as it was in the original code. Is there a way to fix that? Also what do you mean by "glue"? I understand that as my heading font size, image size and heading spacing are all in fixed values, I need to either measure them in some unit multiple of `baselineskip` or compensate the difference with some "glue", correct?

Comment: @tryingout glue is what gets added by `\vspace` etc. But you can discourage a page break before chapters with `\titleformat{\chapter}{\vfil\penalty500\vfilneg\centering\normalfont\large}{\thechapter.}{4ex}{\large\centering}` insead of `\filbreak`

Comment: I don't really know where and how you got all that expertise but your suggestions worked! I obviously lack some basic knowledge to work on a book thus a few questions: 1) and the main, what would you recommend to start with to compile a perfect `book-class` fiction book? What to read? (this one probably deserves a separate post) 2) in values like `{6ex plus 4ex minus 1ex}` I noticed that only first value matters, so how do you come up with the 2nd and 3rd? 3) do I still need to measure the images after the chapter name in some unit multiple of `baselineskip`? If yes, what unit that would be?